# What use of exclusion and inclusion method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i read rails doc found `exclusion` and `inclusion` method this description

**2.4 exclusion**

This helper validates that the attributes' values are not included in a given set. In fact, this set can be any enumerable object.

**but not understand use it**

**2.6 inclusion**

same define

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `exclusion` you can validate the value for the attribute you're specifying doesn't take the value of any of those for the `in` option.

Take an example of a Car model, where you have the price, specs, brand, etc (not normalized). You can prevent a car with brand Toyota to be created, you add that specific brand, and at the moment of saving the record, due to the validation, it will raise the error, and the transaction will suffer a rollback.

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  validates :brand, exclusion: { in: %w[hyundai toyota peugeot] }
end

car = Car.new(price: 11111, brand: 'hyundai')
car.valid? # false
car.errors.messages
# => {:brand=>["is reserved"]}
car.save
#   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
#   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
# => false
```

You can create any car, as long as the brand isn't "hyundai", "toyota" or "peugeot".

Note the validation is case sensitive. Isn't the same "Hyundai" or "hyundai" (or any other).

[`ActiveRecordValidations#inclusion`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion) is the opposite of exclusion, it checks the value can only be any of those on the `in` option.